# Where is the link to Meta and Help center in new nav?

Tags: support, meta, top-bar, help-center

So I noticed the top navigation size has increased by about 50% which somehow also caused some items to disappear from it. Or I just can't see them. I usually used Help - Meta to get to the meta.SO. So how am I supposed to do it now except for writing in the URL?

I'm not sure if I'll be able to make userscript to bring the old nav back, so I'm quite concerned about help center and meta links for other sites, which are not in my browser history.

Comment: Meta is in the list of sites if you click the hamburger icon. Help center is however one valid concern raised by many users previously

Comment: You are obviously [one of the 88,000 clicks](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/?cb=1) that used the nav-bar...welcome to an elite group. Unfortately they felt people would be more interested in clicking Jobs and Documentation instead of learning how to use the site correctly.

Comment: @Lankymart Eek. It's so... different.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I find the justifications for doing it *flakey* at best.

Comment: Oh my God, they killed Kenny.

Comment: open this post in your browser in private / incognito mode to find where it should be (prominently marked question icon to the left of Stack Exchange icon)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The link to Meta is still in the site switcher, which is the rightmost icon:

> [image: screenshot of site switcher]

The help link is currently not available in the top bar for more experienced users, [but that is under review](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update):

> Access to Help - this is currently available in the nav for anonymous & low rep users. We’re not sure it’s necessary as a persistent nav item, but we are thinking about it

You can still go to the help page via the footer:

> [image: screenshot of help in footer]

Answer (score 5):

Since there's enough room to display a Winter Bash icon, it seems [Stack Overflow has decided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301902/295232) to re-add the Help menu for everybody:

[image]

Comment: I hadn't even noticed until you posted this! Super happy for that!

Comment: Noticed just now and great to see the help icon re-added on top bar for all users.